# Which one is better to create a web application? web2py or cherrypy

Tags: javascript, python, web2py, cherrypy

I am using Raspberry Pi to function as a mini web server. At first, i came across web2py and started to learn it. It was tough for a beginner like me. Later, a friend in a forum introduced CherryPy to me and i started to work on the web application skeleton that he gave me. Soon, I abandoned web2py and proceeded with cherrypy as it is fairly straightforward.

Somehow, I think web2py could be a good choice too. Web application for both are written in python, with html, css and javascripts. So whatever i've done using cherrypy may be possible to transfer over to web2py. (is it true?)

I would like to find out what are the main differences between those 2 and their respective pros and cons. I hope to find out more about fellow users' experiences in using web2py and cherrypy. In such way, future visitors can make a comparison before they proceed in choosing which one to use. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

web2py is using MVC model and each of the scripts are nicely separated. It can be deployed at pythoneverywhere.com. not too sure about cherrypy.

Answer (score 1):

I found a good source of information to compare between web2py and others. Here's the link: http://www.web2py.com/examples/static/web2py_vs_others.pdf